# vim delete single space between (character/number) and (character number)

Tags: vim

I have a text file with four variables (TA 000, TB 111, T2 333, T56 R88), separated by 3 single spaces among each other like:

```
TA 000   TB 111   T2 333   T56 R88
```

Is it possible to erase the single space within the variables with vim, maintaining intact the 3 spaces that separate the variables?

```
TA000   TB111   T2333   T56R88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. One approach is with *capturing groups*, capturing the words + single space + numbers, and reassembling only with words + numbers:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\) \(\d\+\)/\1\2/g
```

Another approach matches only the single space (and replaces it with nothing), asserting (but not matching) the stuff around it:

```
:%s/\w\zs \ze\d//g
```

The `\zs` and `\ze` (you can look up anything here via `:h /\zs` etc.) are specific to Vim. A variation (that would work in other regular expression engines, too) would be using positive *lookahead* and *lookbehind*, but the syntax is more complex.

If the three spaces have special meaning (to limit the matching places), you can incorporate those into both approaches, too. I leave that to you, as such relatively easy problems provide great learning experiences :-)